# Looking for a simple way to forbid specific software from writing to the registry

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, uac

I am working at a company with an admin account, which means my account has full access to the system and registry. I love to run portable software with my usb drive but some of the software is automatically attached to the menu right click shell or will modify the file associations, so I have to manually "fix" it every time.

My concern is:

1. If I want to protect a specific registry key, I can set permission to read-only, BUT I have to do it one by one (or manually). Some "heavy registry  software" like a video player, can always register a lot of file associations like *.avi, *.flv, *.mp4.. etc
2. Running software with UAC can protect some critical registry keys, BUT UAC will required a reboot to take effect which is frustrating.
3. Running software as a standard user can protect some critical registry keys, BUT since this is my office computer, I would like to minimize making changes to system as much as possible.
4. Running software with Sandbox or some AntiVirus registry protection program sounds great, BUT I am working with an office computer, I would like to minimize the installation of software.

Is there any other way to protect the registry from being changed by specific software? Thanks.

Comment: Don't give local Administrator access, or if on a domain, prevent it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the local `Administrator` account for your regular business.

However, you can create just a "regular" admin account so that you are able to turn on UAC.

I know that you are frustrated because UAC takes a restart to take effect, but you are better off living with UAC on permanently to handle 75% of your cases (that most programs have *too* many privileges) than to UAC turned off for the other 25% (Command Prompt, etc).

If you are annoyed that UAC will annoy you for every little thing, there's a slider:

[image: UAC settings]

Whenever you need more privileges, just use `Run as Administrator` on the program. Simple as that, and the only annoyance is just having to restart the program in question.